# iOS : Why can't I get mapkit to display a custom annotation pin image?

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

figured that using my own custom pin image for annotations would be super easy.

But I have never been able to get it to work, and I have no idea why!

I am simply using:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnotation";
    CustomAnnotationView * customAnnotationView = (CustomAnnotationView *) [self.mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if(!customAnnotationView)
    {
        customAnnotationView=[[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotationWithImage:annotation
                                                                       reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier 
                                                                   annotationViewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"]];
    }

    customAnnotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"];

    customAnnotationView.canShowCallout= YES;

    return customAnnotationView;
}
```

I assumed that this should work, as a UIImage is what it is wanting, and I do have the .png file in my project.

It never uses my image, but just the standard red pin. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Refer this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Did you define your `delegate` for your `MKMapView`? Have you put a breakpoint or `NSLog` in here to make sure your `viewForAnnotation` is getting called?
2. You haven't shared your `CustomAnnotationView` interface/implementation details, but you don't need to subclass `MKAnnotationView` unless you're doing something special in there. If you're just replacing the image, you can just do:

   ```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
   {
       if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
           return nil;
       }

       NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"CustomViewAnnotation";
       MKAnnotationView* annotationView = [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

       if (annotationView) {
           annotationView.annotation = annotation;
       } else {
           annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
       }

       annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"];
       annotationView.canShowCallout= YES;

       return annotationView;
   }
   ```

   Clearly, though, if you're doing something interesting (like custom annotation when a pin is dragged or dropped), then go ahead and have your `CustomAnnotationView` subclass `MKAnnotationView`. It just depends upon what you're trying to do.
3. Unrelated to your original question, I'd suggest:

   - that your `viewForAnnotation` method just use the local `mapView` variable rather than referencing a class property, `self.mapView` (though they're undoubtedly the same),
   - that you contemplate renaming your custom init method. So instead of:

     ```
     customAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotationWithImage:annotation
                                                                      reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier 
                                                                  annotationViewImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"]];
     ```

     that you'd do something like:

     ```
     customAnnotationView = [[CustomAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                             reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier 
                                                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_location_pin.png"]];
     ```

If you're still having troubles, share some of your `CustomAnnotationView` code with us.

Answer (score 2):

I think It's support to you.can you try this code.and you can add my annotation .h and .m files and do some changes My annotataion

my annotation.h

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

        CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
        NSString*               title;
        NSString*               subtitle;
        UIImage*                image;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign)   CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
    @property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               title;
    @property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               subtitle;
    @property (nonatomic, retain)       UIImage*                image;

    @end


my annotation.m


        #import "MyAnnotation.h"


    @implementation MyAnnotation

    @synthesize title;
    @synthesize subtitle;
    @synthesize coordinate;
    @synthesize image;
    - (void)dealloc 
    {
        [super dealloc];
        self.title = nil;
        self.subtitle = nil;
        self.image=nil;
    }
    @end





       - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation

    {

        //NSLog(@"welcome into the map view annotation");

        // if it's the user location, just return nil.

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])

            return nil;

        // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
        static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier]autorelease];

        //annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-1.png"];

        //[pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-1.png"]];

        UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:((MyAnnotation *)annotation).image];
        CGRect newBounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 32.0, 32.0);
        [thumbnailImageView setBounds:newBounds];
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = thumbnailImageView;
        [thumbnailImageView release];

        //UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:featuredDealcouponImage1];
        // [pinView setImage:featuredDealcouponImage1];
        pinView.animatesDrop=NO;

        pinView.canShowCallout=YES;

        pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(_annotation_btn_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;




        return pinView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are subclassing

```
NSObject <MKAnnotation>
```

and not

```
MKPinAnnotationView
```